# What do the difficulties mean?

Tags: dayz-2012

When selecting a server, I see Veteran, Regular, and Recruit.  Do these designations have any in game effects or are they more like reflections of the general attitude of the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [DayZ Wiki](http://www.dayzwiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Servers):

> Servers differ in difficulty level, regular difficulty allows third-person, has a crosshair, and allows you to see other players nameplates. Veteran servers do not permit these.

Additionally, I found [this forum post](http://dayzmod.com/forum/index.php?/topic/35747-recruitregularveteranexpert-difficulties/) which relates to the proximity detection of zombies according to the difficulty level:

> - **Recruit Difficulty** - Zombies will be highlighted regardless of their location. (shown as white dots around the edges of your screen or through walls)
> - **Regular Difficulty** - Zombies will be highlighted *only* around the edges of your screen (again shown as white dots)
> - **Veteran Difficulty** - There will be no highlighting of zombies anywhere on your screen.

As far as I can tell, the proximity detection is the *only* difference between Recruit and Regular, while the lack of third-person and cross-hair support is the main difference in Veteran.

It is worth noting, however, that your mileage may vary depending on the server, as any of these options (third-person/crosshairs, etc.) can be disabled at any time by the server admins, allegedly.

Comment: There are actually four difficulty settings, and from everything I've read, the difference is in the **default** settings; you can set up a recruit server to not allow those things as well.  Also, some config-options cannot be changed on veteran/expert.

Comment: To chime in with @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft, the wiki is just listing the defaults for those levels as those settings are configurable on the server (I have played on a veteran where I can go in 3rd person). It is the info from the forum post that is most often the difference.